# Using nested LINQ queries and collections of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, collections, nested

I am using a two LINQ queries(nested)

Here's what I want my query to achieve:

In my inner query

- Retrieve a collection of `UserLocation` objects using two conditions

In my outer query

- Retrieve a filtered collection of `User` objects where `User.UID` matches the property `UserLocation.UID` of each `UserLocation` object from the collection in the inner query.

I'm almost there code-wise, I'm just missing the final step -- I don't know how to get the outer query to enumerate through the `UserLocation` collection and match the `UID`.

In my code I have two queries, the top one is a working example of getting the `FullName` property of a `User` object using the inner query and the conditions I need(as well as matching `UID`).

The second query is the one I am having trouble with. What am I missing?

```
            ownerLiteral.Text = 
            Users.First(u => u.UID.Equals(
                UserLocations.First(s => s.IsOwner == true && s.LID.Equals(building.LID)).UID)).FullName;

        var propertyteam = 
            Users.Where(c => c.UID.Equals(
                UserLocations.Where(x => x.IsPropertyTeam == true && x.LID.Equals(building.LID))));
```

### Edit: Fixed the problem

I had forgotten that `UserLocations` was a member of `Users` -- I shortened down my query and used `.Any` to select the `UserLocations` members that fit my conditions, then just return the `User`.

In the first query I return the `FullName` for the `User` object.

In the second query I now return a collection of `User` objects that fit the conditions.

For those that are interested I bind the second query to a DataList and then evaluate for their FullName in the user control.

```
ownerLiteral.Text = 
            Users.First(
            u => u.UserLocations.Any(
                ul => ul.IsOwner == true && ul.LID.Equals(building.LID))).FullName;

var propertyteam = 
            Users.Where(
            u => u.UserLocations.Any(
                ul => ul.IsPropertyTeam && ul.LID.Equals(building.LID)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class relationships are confusing me, but I think your problem is that you're trying to treat a collection of `UserLocation` objects (`Where()` returns an `IEnumerable`) as a single `UserLocation`

I think this might do it:

```
var propertyteam = LoggedInUser.ExtranetUser.Company.Users
  .Where(c => c.UID.IsPropertyTeam == true && c.UID.LID.Equals(building.LID));
```

**Edit, based on further information:**

So maybe this is what you're looking for?

```
var uidsWhoArePartOfThePropertyTeamForThisBuilding
  = UserLocations.Where(x => x.IsPropertyTeam && x.LID == building.LID)
  .Select(x => x.UID);
```

Assuming the UID member of a UserLocation is a whole User object, and not just some int ID for a User.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I'll clean up the code a little bit. I do want to return a collection of UserLocations though. UserLocations is a "linked" database between Locations and Users and specifies whether they are connected. Each LID(location id) is matched to a UID(user id) and then has the properties IsOwner or IsPropertyTeam. User only contains UID.

Comment: See my edit above. Are you sure you want a collection of UserLocations? What are you going to do with it? o_O

Comment: Close enough, I'm editing my question to include the answer I found. I had forgotten that `UserLocations` was also a property of `Users`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To write a T-SQL type IN clause, in LINQ you would use Contains.  This would be where I would start:

```
    var userlocations = LoggedInUser.ExtranetUser.UserLocations.Select(ul => ul.UID);
    var propertyteam = LoggedInUser.ExtranetUser.Company.Users.Where(userlocations.Contains(u => u.UID));
```